# Ubuntu--cant create new database with phpmyadmin its writes: no privileges

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, users

Hi I have probem with phpmyadmin on ubuntu (My desktop computer):
cant create new database with phpmyadmin its writes: no privileges.
How privaleges can be enable that i will able to create new database?
Thanks

---

I try your solution and I get this result on console:

**The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement**

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the mysql user that you're using with phpmyadmin does not have the Create_priv privilege (probably does not have other privileges that you'll want to use, either).

Try to set it like this:

```
GRANT CREATE ON yourdb.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

More on Grant syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).